# Is there any way to show interactives plots in the plot viewer with vscode?

Tags: python, matplotlib, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I'm using the Microsoft Python extension for Visual Studio Code which since June supports a plot viewer with the Python Interactive window. I'm trying (with no success) to make interactive plots with matplotlib in vscode as I do in Jupyter Notebook using the magic code `%matplotlib notebook` at the top of the code, in order to use the data zoom cursor and the data tracker as I show in the next image:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/avMuq.png

Is there any way to use the plot viewer to show interactive plots?

Comment: matplot has function [ion()](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.ion.html) - "Interactive ON".

Comment: It does not look like VS studio's jupyter server app would support `%matplotlib notebook`.

Comment: @furas I tried that function, didn't work

Comment: it seems not all tools are ready for this function.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a developer on this tool. Currently the plot viewer is just a raw png / svg viewer, interactive plots are not supported. If you wanted to file an issue on this you could on our GitHub here:
https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python

Comment: Thanks, I'll do that.

Comment: If you file an issue, please cross-reference it back here